# Need for /dev nodes at the time of accessing Linux Drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

I am trying to understand the necessity of /dev node in Linux 2.6 . I do understand that, in Linux 2.4 days, entries under this directory were necessary so as to access the Drivers from userspace. But in 2.6 version we use /sys interface inorder to achieve this. But still could find entries for within /dev directory .

As a step towards understanding the same, I changed the name parameter (this was the name in my /dev directory ) , within "miscdevice" object, that was passed as input to "misc_register" API  within my Sensor driver and still the driver worked the same way.

Are there any drivers which still relay on /dev node for their working ? If yes what are they ?

Thanks,
Venkatesh.

Comment: An application often need to read or write to a device thru `/dev` ; how could it do that without a device inode (conventionally located under `/dev`)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two different things...

The files in `/dev` are the actual devices that you read and write to in order to interact with a device - so if you want to write to a serial port you open the file in `/dev` that represents it and write to it.

The files in `/sys` expose various attributes of the device to userspace so that programs can, for example, see what features a device supports, or hos it is configured. In a few cases the files in `/sys` can be written to in order to change the configuration of the device in some way.